# Callback function executed first

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I made the following code:

```
function popup(content,callback){
// create the overlay
var $overlay = $('<div />').appendTo('body');
    $overlay.attr('class','overlay');
// create a popup
var $popup = $('<div />').appendTo('body');
    $popup.attr('class','popup');
// add the image
if(typeof content.imageUrl !== 'undefined'){
    var $popup_image = $('<img />').appendTo($popup);
        $popup_image.attr('src',content.imageUrl);
        $popup_image.attr('class','popup_img');
};
// create a popup title
var $popup_title = $('<h1 />').appendTo($popup);
    $popup_title.attr('class','popup_h1');
    $popup_title.html(content.title);
// create a popup body
var $popup_body = $('<p />').appendTo($popup);
    $popup_body.attr('class','popup_p');
    $popup_body.html(content.text);
// create a popup close
var $popup_close = $('<span />').appendTo($popup);
    $popup_close.attr('class','close');
    $popup_close.html('x');
// create the fadeIn/fadeOut speed
if(typeof content.speed !== undefined){
    var popup_fadespeed = content.speed;
} else {
    var popup_fadespeed = 'slow';
};
    // bind the close function to $popup_close
    $popup_close.bind('click',function(){
        $popup.fadeOut(popup_fadespeed);
        $overlay.fadeOut(popup_fadespeed);
    });
    // bind the close function to $overlay
    $overlay.bind('click',function(){
        $popup.fadeOut(popup_fadespeed);
        $overlay.fadeOut(popup_fadespeed);
    });
    // show the overlay
    $overlay.fadeIn(popup_fadespeed);
    // show the popup
    $popup.fadeIn(popup_fadespeed);

    if(callback && typeof(callback) === "function"){
        return callback();
    } else {
        return;
    }}
```

It creates a popup in my window, and everything workes find, exept for the callback.

when I do something like this:

```
$("#test").click(
function(){popup(
{
    title : 'title',
    text : 'text',
    imageUrl : 'http://localhost/frontend/media/images/logo.png',
    speed : 'slow'
},
function(){$('body').css('background','red');}
)});
```

Now the body background changes before the popup shows. When I test it with an alert, the alert also shows up  before the popup (so it looks like the callback function is executed first).

Can someone help me out with this? Or locate the mistake I made in the code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: My guess it has to do with you adding an image to the DOM and image being loaded asynchronously so you end up running you code before the content is actually visible. Probably you can find a use to [images loaded plugin](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded)

Comment: `return callback()` calls the function and then returns its return value. There's nothing there to make it wait until after the fade in effect, which will happen asynchronously. Have you tried `$popup.fadeIn(popup_fadespeed, callback);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the last to this:

```
if(callback && typeof(callback) === "function"){
   $popup_image.load(callback);
    } else {
        return;
    }}
```

`.load` is a wrap of dom element `img`'s `onload`, which if you put some function into it, it'll executes after image is loaded. [jquey.load](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

Add [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/re4cjt3s/) to show it works.

Comment: when I add that piece of code, nothing shows up (like an alert). When I set $popup.load(callback()) (with the () after callback), the callback is fired before the popup is loaded.

Comment: Oops, i messed up with `$popup` and `$popup_image`, edited, try again?

Comment: Doesn't work either. But I got the solution now (see comments at my first post)